# preventing useState to render the initial value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

If you look to my JSX I am trying to create **sizes** from the `product` object the problem is when I loop throguh the `product.size.map()` it threw an error that says `product` is undefined.

How to solve this?

**update**
I was able to do some workaround but I am sure it is not considered as a best practice.

```js
import React , {useState , useEffect} from 'react'
import { Row, Col, Image, ListGroup, Card, Button } from 'react-bootstrap'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'
import Rating from '../components/Rating'
import axios from 'axios'


const ProductScreen = ({match}) => {
    const [product , setProduct] = useState({})   
    useEffect(()=>{
        let componentMounted = true
        const fetchProducts =  async ()=>{
            const {data} = await axios.get(`http://172.30.246.130:5000/api/products/${match.params.id}`)
            if(componentMounted){
                setProduct(data) 
            }
        }
        fetchProducts()
        return () => {
            componentMounted = false
        }
    },[match])
    if(Object.keys(product).length===0) return null // this is the workaround I have done what do you think?
    else{
    return (
        <>
       
            <Link className='btn btn-light my-3' to='/'>
            Go Back
            </Link>
            <Row>
                <Col md={6}>
                <Image src={product.image} alt={product.name} />
                </Col>
                <Col md={3}>
                    <ListGroup variant='flush'>
                        <ListGroup.Item>
                <h3>{product.name}</h3>
                        </ListGroup.Item>

                <ListGroup.Item>
                    <Rating rating={product.rating} reviews={product.numReviews}/>
                </ListGroup.Item>
                <ListGroup.Item>
                <strong> Price: ${product.price}</strong>
                </ListGroup.Item>
                <ListGroup.Item>
                    <strong>Description :</strong> {product.description}
                </ListGroup.Item>
                    </ListGroup>
                </Col>
                <Col md={3}>
                    <Card>
                        <ListGroup>
                            <ListGroup.Item>
                                <Row>
                                    <Col>
                                    Price :
                                    </Col>
                                    <Col>
                                    <strong>${product.price}</strong>
                                    </Col>
                                </Row>
                            </ListGroup.Item>
                            <ListGroup.Item>
                                <Row>
                                    <Col>
                                    Status :
                                    </Col>
                                    <Col>
                                    <strong>{product.countInStock > 0 ? 'In Stock' : "Out Of Stock"}</strong>
                                    </Col>
                                </Row>
                            </ListGroup.Item>
                            <ListGroup.Item>
                                <Row>
                                    <Col>
                                    Sizes :
                                    </Col>
                                    <Col>
                                  {product.size.map(s=><Button key={s} className='p-2 m-1'>{s}</Button>)}
                                    </Col>
                                </Row>
                            </ListGroup.Item>
                            <ListGroup.Item className='d-grid gap-2'>
                                <Button type='button' disabled={product.countInStock === 0}>
                                    Add To Cart
                                </Button>
                            </ListGroup.Item>
                        </ListGroup>
                    </Card>
                
                </Col>
            </Row>
        </>
    )
}}

export default ProductScreen
```

```js
import React , {useState , useEffect} from 'react'
import { Row, Col, Image, ListGroup, Card, Button } from 'react-bootstrap'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'
import Rating from '../components/Rating'
import axios from 'axios'


const ProductScreen = ({match}) => {
    const [product , setProduct] = useState({})   
    useEffect(()=>{
        let componentMounted = true
        const fetchProducts =  async ()=>{
            const {data} = await axios.get(`http://172.30.246.130:5000/api/products/${match.params.id}`)
            if(componentMounted){
                setProduct(data) 
            }
        }
        fetchProducts()
        return () => {
            componentMounted = false
        }
    },[match,product ])
    
    return (
        <>
            <Link className='btn btn-light my-3' to='/'>
            Go Back
            </Link>
            <Row>
                <Col md={6}>
                <Image src={product.image} alt={product.name} />
                </Col>
                <Col md={3}>
                    <ListGroup variant='flush'>
                        <ListGroup.Item>
                <h3>{product.name}</h3>
                        </ListGroup.Item>

                <ListGroup.Item>
                    <Rating rating={product.rating} reviews={product.numReviews}/>
                </ListGroup.Item>
                <ListGroup.Item>
                <strong> Price: ${product.price}</strong>
                </ListGroup.Item>
                <ListGroup.Item>
                    <strong>Description :</strong> {product.description}
                </ListGroup.Item>
                    </ListGroup>
                </Col>
                <Col md={3}>
                    <Card>
                        <ListGroup>
                            <ListGroup.Item>
                                <Row>
                                    <Col>
                                    Price :
                                    </Col>
                                    <Col>
                                    <strong>${product.price}</strong>
                                    </Col>
                                </Row>
                            </ListGroup.Item>
                            <ListGroup.Item>
                                <Row>
                                    <Col>
                                    Status :
                                    </Col>
                                    <Col>
                                    <strong>{product.countInStock > 0 ? 'In Stock' : "Out Of Stock"}</strong>
                                    </Col>
                                </Row>
                            </ListGroup.Item>
                            <ListGroup.Item>
                                <Row>
                                    <Col>
                                    Sizes :
                                    </Col>
                                    <Col>
                                   {console.log(product)}
                                    </Col>
                                </Row>
                            </ListGroup.Item>
                            <ListGroup.Item className='d-grid gap-2'>
                                <Button type='button' disabled={product.countInStock === 0}>
                                    Add To Cart
                                </Button>
                            </ListGroup.Item>
                        </ListGroup>
                    </Card>
                
                </Col>
            </Row>
        </>
    )
}

export default ProductScreen
```

Comment: *"it threw an error that says product is undefined."* I bet you it said `product.size` is `undefined` (not `product`). *"when I loop throguh the `product.size.map()`..."* `product.size.map` doesn't appear anywhere in the code you've provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't prevent the initial state being rendered.

(I've added an update to the bottom related to the updated question.)

If that component can't be usefully rendered without the `product`, then `product` should be a prop it receives, not a  state member it fetches. The fetch should be in the parent component.

But if you want the fetch to remain in the component, you need to set a marker value (like `null`) and branch your rendering based on that marker value, e.g.:

```
if (!product) {
    return /* ...render a "loading" message... */;
}
// ..render `product` here...
```

---

Re your edited question: You seem to be having an issue with `product.size.map(/*...*/)`. If we look at your initial state, you have:

```
const [product, setProduct] = useState({});
```

Since it doesn't have a `size` property, `product.size` is `undefined` and `product.size.map` will fail with an error about `product.size` being `undefined`.

You haven't shown the code trying to do the `product.size.map`, but you have various options.

You could use a guard:

```
{product.size && product.size.map(/*...*/)}
```

You could include an empty array in the initial state:

```
const [product, setProduct] = useState({size: []});
```

Comment: Thank you, it would be nice of you if you can check my edited question as it seems the real problem I am facing.

Comment: Thank you so much for your solution, my problem is solved now and that makes sense.

Comment: Glad that helped! :-) Happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

Remove `product` from the dependencies of `useEffect` as that will trigger the callback and causes an infinite loop.

```
useEffect(() => {
  ...      
},[match])
```

To not render anything until `product` is fetched, use a falsy value like `undefined/null` as the initial state:

```
const [product , setProduct] = useState();
```

and check `product` before returing the JSX:

```
if(!product) return null;

return (
 <>
  <Link className='btn btn-light my-3' to='/'>
 ...
)
```

Comment: Good point about the dependency, I would even use `match.params.id`,  match might have other params that other components depend on, but this one doesn't.  Might save some renders.  The return null short circuit is something I do too if the fetch is likely to be short.

Comment: @Ramesh Reddy thank you for your answer, if you look to my jsx I am using the ```product``` object, and when I console log it, it seems to have two values, the first one is ```{}``` and the second one is the object I want. the problem is when I render image from the ```person``` object it says first undefined which is super weird to me.

Comment: I edited my question to the problem I am currently facing

Comment: @TankOne You can still follow my answer to fix the error in the updated question